# How to make back icon to behave same as physical back button in Android?

Tags: android, back

I have `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_second_activitity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
</activity>
```

While I hit the back icon of `SecondActivity`, it's more likely that `MainActivity` is pushed on `SecondActivity`. Instead, physical back button will make `SecondActivity` pops up and back to `MainActivity`.

How can I make the back arrow icon to behave the same as physical back button?

Comment: are you talking about back button of actionbar?

Comment: Yes, Apurva. I'm talking about the back button of actionbar.

Answer (score 11):

Physical back button and icon back button aren't supposed to work in the same way according to the google's guidelines. But if you want to change it's behavior then you need to override it's functionality by doing the next:

On your SecondActivity override `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();    //Call the back button's method
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also you need to remove `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` from your manifest but to avoid the back icon to be removed you need to set it enabled:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();  //Make sure you are extending ActionBarActivity
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    //It's also possible to use getSupportActionBar()
}
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, I tried your solution, but in this case, back icon will disappear if I remove `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` from my manifest.

Comment: @CarlosJ, could you please share the relevant reference from the official docs or the android developers blog about: `Physical back button and icon back button aren't supposed to work in the same way according to the google's guidelines`

Comment: never mind, found it. https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 6):

Carlos' answer works. There is also another way which I think is more straight forward: just add a click listener directly to the back icon.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this behaviour, you can define the launchMode of your MainActivity as a singleTop activity. This is easely done in your Manifest by adding following line:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_second_activitity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

If you want to support API 15 and lower, I would recommend adding the meta-data element inside your SecondActivity as well, as you can see above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add 3 things to define what activity you want to go on back pressed, not push that activity onto the stack and to make back button behave same as physical back button.

**1.** Define the activity you want to go in when `back button` is pressed.

In your `manifest` file's `activity` tag include

```
<activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data              //Use meta-data if you are using support library
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
```

**2.** Override `onBackPressed` method inside your `SecondActivity.class` file so as not to push `MainActivity` onto the stack when back button is pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

**3.** Use `showHomeAsUpEnabled()` to set back button in actionBar.

`ActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` or `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` if you are using support library.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       int mCount = pager.getCurrentItem();

        if(mCount>0){
            pager.setCurrentItem(0,false);
            firsticon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2B8C57"));
            secondicon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            thirdicon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            fourthicon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            fifthicon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        }else{
            this.finish();
        }

    }
```

Comment: this is for switching to first tab from other tab on back pressed in bottom view